# Do relative clauses starting with “deren” behave like subordinate clauses?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, relative-clause

If you start a sentence with *deren,* do you have to use the same syntax as a subordinate clause? By that I mean, do you have to push the verbs to the end of the clause?

Example:

> Sie haben Ihre Hunde gestreichelt, deren Welpen gerade ankommen sind.
>
> (They petted their dogs, whose puppies just arrived.)

Comment: It should be "attributive clauses" (Attributsätze) rather than "adjective clauses".

Comment: Or *relative clause*, as explained in the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

> If you start a sentence with *deren*, do you have to use the same syntax as a subordinate clause?

**No.** The word order of your example:

> Sie haben Ihre Hunde gestreichelt, **deren** Welpen gerade ankommen **sind**.

Can be changed (by changing the meaning, of course):

> Sie haben Ihre Hunde gestreichelt, **deren** Welpen **sind** gerade ankommen.

In your example the second part of the sentence **is** a relative clause (describing the word "Hunde"). Therefore the word order is of course the word order of a relative clause.

In the second example we have **two sentences** which are separated by a comma. (Sometimes writers separate sentences by a comma instead of a period to indicate these clauses belong together.) Therefore the word order of both sentences is the word order of a main clause.

Comment: The answer "no" should probably be changed to "not in every case".

Comment: @RHa I understood the question in a way that the user wants to know if a sentence which is **not** a relative clause has that word order when it begins with "*deren*".

Comment: Using **deren** as a means to connect two main clauses makes it a *demonstrative pronoun*, when you use it to connect a relative clause, it's obviously a *relative pronoun*. So, it's actually two different words that happen to sound and spell the same. You'll also normally find two different entries in dictionaries.

Answer (score 5):

A term like *adjective clause* is not defined in German. But defined are:

- relative clause = Relativsatz
- subordinate clause = Nebensatz

I'm not an expert in English grammar, but I think that *adjective clause* and *relative clause* are quite the same thing.

In German *Relativsätze* are a subset of *Nebensätze*, i.e. every Relativsatz is a Nebensatz, but there exist Nebensätze which are not Relativsätze.

---

### Relativsatz

- A German *Relativsatz* can be an attribute of a part of speech in the main clause (»attributiver Relativsatz«):

  > - Sabine, **die gerade kocht,** gibt dem Kind Kartoffeln. *(related to the subject)*
  > - Sabine gibt dem Kind, **das ständig schreit,** Kartoffeln. *(related to the dative object)*
  > - Sabine gibt dem Kind Kartoffeln, **die sie vor dem Kochen schält.** *(related to the accusative object)*
- But a German *Relativsatz* can also be a part of the main clause itself (»freier Relativsatz«):

  > - Sabine gibt dem Kind, **was es wünscht.** *(The relative clause itself is an accusative object in the main clause)*
  > - **Wer Kartoffeln möchte,** bekommt auch welche. *(The relative clause itself is the subject of the main clause)*
  > - Jeder kann essen, **wo er möchte.** (The relative clause itself is a local adverbial in the main clause)*

Usually a Relativsatz starts with a relative pronoun (*der, die, das; welcher, welche, welches*) or with a relative adverb (*wo, wie, da, als*).

But sometimes also longer phrases can be used to start a Relativsatz:

> Der Täter, **für dessen Ergreifung** eine hohe Belohnung ausgesetzt wurde, floh.

---

### Nebensatz

In German a Nebensatz is a part of a sentence that depends on the so-called *matrix clause*.
A Nebensatz can be a *Relativsatz* (see above), but also:

- Subjekt- und Objektsätze

  > **Dass du alleine bist,** ist nicht gut.  *(Subjektsatz)*
  >   Ich weiß, **dass du alleine bist.** *(Objektsatz)*
- Adverbialsätze
  Some examples:

  > **Falls ich gewinne,** musst du bezahlen. *(Konditionalsatz)*
  >   Es war besser, **als ich es mir erträumt hatte.** *(Komparativsatz)*
  >   Er kam zu spät, **weil er verschlafen hatte.** *(Kausalsatz)*

In all *Nebensätze* the finite verb has to be the last word in this Nebensatz. (In a *Hauptsatz* the finite verb stands at position 2.)